# Use of 'whichever comes/occurs first'

Tags: meaning

I could not solve this by my own.
Hope someone could help me..

Below is a sample clause from a contract.

The goods will be guaranteed for a period of 12 month after your receipt of our confirmation letter, or 10 month from the first inspect date, which ever expires/comes/occurs first.

*whichever expires first > This is clear

*which ever comes/occurs first >  same meaning as '...expires first' OR it is talking about the guarantee begin date (receipt of confirmation letter/first inspection date)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sense of oddness may come from the expectation that there are multiple things expiring when you see *whichever expires first*.

Here are the dates:

- D1: 12 month[s] after your receipt of our confirmation letter
- D2: 10 month[s] from the first inspect date

The sentence then becomes "The goods will be guaranteed until D1 or D2, whichever expires/comes/occurs first."

There is only one guarantee mentioned, with two possible termination (expiry) dates. So *expires*, as a normal English word (i.e. not considering any legal or specially defined sense), naturally refers to expiry due to D1 or expiry due to D2. That is, the three terms *expires first*, *comes first* and *occurs first* are equivalent.

(*Disclaimer: this is not legal advice. It's not even any sort of advice.*)